# django - data doesn't appear on html side

Tags: python, django, sqlite, jinja2

I created a simple html page that has a navbar with a dropdown menu containing many categories.
when I run the server the menu items don't appear, but when I write a line to print the result on the command it is populated from the database.

"view.py"

```
def categories(request):
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()
    # print(all_categories)
    return {'all categories': all_categories}
```

html page

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'store' %}"> All </a>
                        </li>

                        {% for category in all_categories %}
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> {{ category.name | capfirst }} </a>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
```

on "setting.py" I added in TEMPLATES this line

```
'store.views.categories',
```

Comment: You can refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render.

Answer (score 0):

According to the html you want to display, the code is as follows:

## views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def categories(request):
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {"all_categories": all_categories}
    return render(request, "your_html_path", context)
```

Comment: it is will be shown in navbar so it has to be available on every single template or page. that why I added it on setting.py, I mean the context.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know the problem that was in writing the name of the key,  by mistake I wrote it without an underscore like this

```
 return {'all categories': all_categories}
```

it should be

```
all_categories
```